# having a problem understanding sum() in python 3.x 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

```
def d(num):
    return sum(divisor(num))

def divisor(num):
    sumo = 0
    for x in range(1,num//2+1):
        if num%x==0:
        print(x)
        return x
    #return(x for x in range(1,num//2+1) if num%x ==0 )

print(d(220))
```

when i try to run this code i get int is not iterable .... when i tried to execute the commented code it runs fine . Can anyone tell me the difference between the commneted code and the used for loop code and what might be the problem using sum()

Comment: Please Fix your indents! And what does divisor() return if the if is never true?

Comment: `divisor` returns a single `int`, not an iterable of `int`s.

Comment: @barny `divisor` will always return 1, since `x%1 == 0` is always true.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted a `yield` in the `for` loop:

```py
def d(num, use_yield=True):
    return sum(divisor(num, use_yield))

def divisor(num, use_yield=True):
    if use_yield:
        for x in range(1, num // 2+1):
            if num % x == 0:
                yield x
    else:
        result = (x for x in range(1, num // 2 + 1) if num % x == 0)
        for x in result:
            yield x

print(d(220))
print(d(220, use_yield=False))
```

**Output**

```
284
284
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a single number and can therefore not be summed. It's failing here:

return sum(divisor(num)) since divisor is returning one number.